# Android MediaPlayer: onErrorListener and onCompletionListener working ab-normally

Tags: android, stream, listener, android-mediaplayer

I have this code part in Android Service class, that uses MediaPlayer. When I start player and turn the phone to the flight mode after some time of playback (for network error emulating), the `onCompletion` listener fires in some time. But `onError` doesn't fire any IO error.

Also, When changing network from Wi-Fi to 3G and back, the stream stops, but there is no Error and `onCompletion` doesn't work too! Despite the fact that playback is stopped. Why does this happen? What's wrong in the code? Can this depend on the phone? Android 2.3.5, HTC Explorer. Obviously playback stopped but there is no error and `onCompletion` doesn't fire.

```
public class PlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

///

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this.playlist="ONERROR";
  switch (what){
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
      Log.e(TAG2, "unknown media playback error");
      break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
      Log.e(TAG2, "server connection died");
    default:
      Log.e(TAG2, "generic audio playback error");
      break;
  }

  switch (extra){
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
      Log.e(TAG2, "IO media error");
      break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED:
      Log.e(TAG2, "media error, malformed");
      break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:
      Log.e(TAG2, "unsupported media content");
      break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
      Log.e(TAG2, "media timeout error");
      break;
    default:
      Log.e(TAG2, "unknown playback error");
      break;
  }


  return true;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this.playlist="COMPLETED";
}

///

this.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, Uri.parse(url));
               this.mplayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
               this.mplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                   this.mplayer.start();
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, prepare MediaPlayer:

```
mPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Then start MediaPlayer:

```
mPlayer.start();
```